# Native Pronunciation of -rr- in the place name Wirral as voiced alveolar stop -d-

Tags: english, phonetics, rhoticity, rhotics

I was surprised to hear the Native Pronunciation of -*rr*- in the place name Wirral as voiced alveolar stop/tap -*d*- in this video as spoken by a native centenarian at the time point 0:47:

[Life Lessons From 100-Year-Olds](https://youtu.be/9AThycGCakk?t=40)

Is this the standard pronunciation for the -rr- in NW England, or is it standard English?
This seems to be the reverse of the American rhoticity of the intervocalic -*t*- in words like "scooter".
I would like to gain greater clarity into the phonetics involved here.
Thank you!

Comment: That doesn’t sound like a voiced [d] to me – or rather, it doesn’t sound like _his_ voiced [d]’s. He’s from 1915, so it would not be unexpected for him to have tapped [ɾ] as the intervocalic allophone of /r/. The sound he makes in _Wirral_ here to me just sounds like a tapped [ɾ] where the contact between tongue and alveolar ridge accidentally ended up just a bit longer than usual. I won’t fault him for having lost a little bit of his finer lingual muscle control at 101 years of age.

Comment: I know a couple of people from the Wirral (albeit much younger than this, both being born in the 90s), and both had fairly standard Northern-influenced RP /r/ in Wirral, definitely not a d, or even a tap. So if it were standard for the region, it doesn't seem to be any more